# Is there always a transformation between canonical variables?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism

Let us suppose that a for a given monogenic and holonomic system we can construct two different collection of canonical variables $\{\underline{q}, \underline{p}\}$ and $\{\underline{Q}, \underline{P}\}$.

Now, my queestion is wethere there necessarily exists a tranformation between the two collections or not.

In my opinion the answer should be positive, for we get the lagrangian coordinates by applying the implicit function theorem to the system of holonomic constraints and then the momenta are just the derivatives of the lagrangian with respect to the lagrangian coordinates derivatives.

---

As always any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!